# Will stock tires from a toyota yaris fit a 2004 cavalier

Tags: tires, toyota, chevrolet

I have a set of stock summer tires from a Toyota Yaris will they fit the stock rims of a 2004 chevy cavalier?

Comment: I am not a tire person so I can't speak for compatibility, but I looked up the tire sizes for anyone else.  2011 Yaris base model sedan has 175/65-14. The 2004 Cavalier base model sedan uses 195/70-14

Comment: Given the difference in width of the tires, we'd also need to know the wheel width for the Cavalier.  Also, tire brand/model is important as some brands/models (even of the same size) can support more wheel widths than others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check the speed rating and load rating of the tyre, normally indicated by something like 91W or 91W...95W etc.  If the cars are drastically different in terms of speed and weight and are also an important factor.

In the event of an accident if you dont have the correctly rated tyres (as specified by the manufacturer) insurers will use that as a get out clause.

Normally on tyres you can go up/down 10mm from the specified tyre width without too much of a problem - i.e. if a manufacturer says "215" then in theory you could go to 205 or 225 width tyres, but I wouldnt push it further than that.

Comment: 215 refers to the width not the diameter or profile, width will not affect the speedo, however the profile would, if you go from a 205/55 to a 215/55 then yes you would affect the speedo.

Answer (score 3):

Compare tire sizes. If the tires you have on your car right now match the recommended factory tires size, and the Yaris has this same size, it should be fine. Mostly tire size and rating is what you compare, assuming stock rims of course.